# Can we load blueprint.xml and start running the rest application in my local IDE(IntelliJ)?

Tags: osgi, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi, cxfrs

I created a junit class by extending CamelBlueprintTestSupport and override the getBlueprintDescriptor() method.

But my blueprint.xml file doesn't have any **camelcontext** . So while running my junit, my tests are not running, I'm getting the below exception.

[image]

If I add some dummy camelcontext, I'm not getting this Exception and my tests are working fine. I'm able to test the jaxrs endpoints.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it should work.

Comment: How can we do it?

Comment: Well, create a maven project based on that archetype and that should generate the code and config for you. Then run it with maven camel:run

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: But my application is not an camel application. It's just plan cxfrs webservice, which will be deployed in fuse. Right now I'm checking the PAX-EXAM for this unit testing. But facing so many issues to configure it. So I want to know what we can to run the application in my local ide and do the testing of each endpoint one by one through junit?